# Adding multiple textboxes to a form in ms-access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to have a line on an **Access** **user-form**. Call it `Item #1`. I would like `Item #1` to be a text box where the user can enter any type of information. So for example, say the user entered "Tutoring" and then next to this was an additional `Textbox` that allowed the user to enter the hours spent tutoring and the date in which the hours were logged.

What I would like is to have a `button` to allow the user to add a second line (or set of `textboxes`) when needed, or a third line, etc. Is this something that can be set up on the **Access** form? Does this need to be coded in **VBA**? Just looking for some tips to provide me some direction on the best approach.

Comment: If the data is stored in a table, use a continuous form bound to the table. Every time you complete a line, a new one is created. If the data should not be stored in a table, it' a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"If the data should not be stored in a table, it' a bit more complicated. "
You would have to make the text boxes not visible when the form loads, and then make each text box visible on the After Update event of the previous box.